# (Using the WHERE clause in SQLite) SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite

I Have code SQLite, but this code not worker in my app

error

```
SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tabellirikWHERE kategori=Pupuh Ginada
```

and this mya code

```
 public ArrayList<Lirik> getAllLirik2(){
    ArrayList<Lirik> arrayList = new ArrayList<Lirik>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MUPUH + "WHERE " + KATEGORY_LIRIK + "=" + "Pupuh Ginada ", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast()==false){
        Lirik lirik = new Lirik(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEYL_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KATEGORY_LIRIK)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(JUDUL)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MUPUH))
        );
        arrayList.add(lirik);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    return arrayList;
}
```

help me, thanks

Comment: try putting Pupuh Ginada in single quotes

Comment: its your space in the name that is the problem

Comment: please describe me, im newbie @Jesse Shellaberger

Comment: please describe me, im newbie @tyczj

Comment: Like @tyczj said, your problem is the space. Wh So putting the name in single quotes when you sent it to your data base should help.
`("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MUPUH + "WHERE " + KATEGORY_LIRIK + "=" + "'Pupuh Ginada'", null).
You also have a space after the name. This won't cause any compile errors, but will ensure that you get  no results...

Comment: @Jesse Shellaberger, this is my error near "=": syntax error (code 1): i using your code, but error near "=": syntax error (code 1): thanks, sorry my english bad

Comment: you sure you got the single quotes? I'm pretty sure that should do it...
`("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MUPUH + "WHERE " + KATEGORY_LIRIK + "=" + " 'Pupuh Ginada' ", null)`

Comment: thanks @Jesse Shellaberger code worker.

Comment: can't you see what's wrong in `tabellirikWHERE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your select clause... it's not properly formatted:

```
SELECT * FROM tabellirikWHERE kategori=Pupuh Ginada
```

You need to place an extra space **BEFORE** "WHERE".
Also as others have said, you need to make sure that you wrap "Pupuh Ginada" in single quotes.  Here is what you need it to look like:

```
SELECT * FROM tabellirik WHERE kategori='Pupuh Ginada'
```

Please do be careful with this though, as this opens you up to possible SQL injection as a security leak if you wind up having that value come from some UI component (ie, and EditText) which allows users to type something in.  You should use the parameterized methods that are provided to you in order to accomplish this:

```
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"Pupuh Ginada"};
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_MUPUH + " WHERE " + KATEGORY_LIRIK + "=?", selectionArgs);
```

Even better is to use [db.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).... but I feel like it's a LOT more wordy and difficult to capture "what" the query is doing.  It uses a bunch of parameters to essentially build your entire query statement.